# keep React-native webview mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am working on an app that will have a web content, living in a webview and some other content and views built using react-native. I am planning to use Webview that react-native provides. I am thinking about the life cycle of the application. I want a way to keep the webview for the application mounted. since when its unmounted, you lose the state of it. I am guessing some navigation routers can help.

Thanks!

Comment: I am currently looking into that with https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation. I kinda have the same use case as you do.